# java.io.FileNotFoundException: When using real server

Tags: java, android, exception

I am beginner in Java and Android Studio. I have written a code by Android Studio and Wamp as server and Genymotion as simulator. all codes work fine and I can interact with mysql by use of my .php files

Then I decide to transfer codes to real server.

but I get this error: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://burj.1shahrvand.com/Burj/BikerLogin.php

**The File is available [check it here](http://burj.1shahrvand.com/Burj/BikerLogin.php) but I get Exception that file not found**

The code is like this:

```
String uri = rp.getUri();
    if(rp.getMethod().equals("GET")){
        uri += "?" + rp.getEncodedParams();
    }


    HttpURLConnection connection;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(rp.getMethod());
        if (rp.getMethod().equals("POST")){
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(rp.getEncodedParams());
            writer.flush();


        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);

        }
        return sb.toString();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("HESAM Original", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
```

I appreciate your Help!

Answer (score 2):

You will get a `FileNotFoundException` if you call `getInputStream` after the server has responded withe a 404 or 410 status code.

If you want to avoid the exception, check that the response status code is a 2xx code.  If it isn't then use `getErrorStream` instead of `getInputStream`.

Comment: The problem is the file is available - when I check it with Explorer or chrome there is no problem - when I request it from my app I get not available.

Comment: I get 403 error. I wrote a ticket to admin. I will publish the answer here.

Comment: A 403 error should result in a different exception.  It actually means "Forbidden".  Typically, that means either forbidden to everyone, or forbidden to someone / something with your authorization.

Comment: Dear @Stephen As U said I checked the server side log and it was 403. Then I turned of MOD Security. now everything works fine. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, There is an option in my Cpanel. It is MOD Security, Just turn it off, after  15 minutes my app worked properly.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why it was on in the first place. Because by disabling it you might have turned off security for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to add the port name(:8080) with the localhost ip address in URL String, like i did:

> String login_url = "http://192.168.0.136:8080/login.php";

Comment: This sounds wrong on many levels. Why would you want to connect to a **local** host IP address? And port numbers often default to 8080 - but that is a configuration aspect. I think there is a lot of blind guessing in your "answer".